# How to check if (u,v) and (v,u) edges are in a given directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph and i want a module to run through all the edges of this graph and check whether (u,v) edge is in this graph and (v,u) edge is in another given graph.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?  `EdgeList` and `MemberQ` are helpful for a direct approach.

Comment: Well i need a loop to go through every edge and to check this, and i don't know how to do that.
I have this code, but it doesn't work

Comment: edgelist = {s -> 1, s -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 3 -> t, 
   4 -> 3, 4 -> t};
createVector[C_] := Module[{newVec {}, l = Length[C], a, b},
  For[i = 0, i < Length[edgelist], i++,
    For[j = 0, j < l, j++,
       If[edgelist[i] == C[j], Append[newVec, 1]; Break,
        If[
         MatchQ[edgelist[i], {__a -> __b}] && 
          MatchQ[C[i], {__b -> __a}], Append[newVec, -1]; Break, 
         Append[newVec, 0];
         ];
        ]
      ]
     newVec
    ];

Comment: I don't understand; what's all that looping about?  If you have an edge list why can't you simply check to see if your edge is in it?

Comment: can you give me a sample code how to check this? for example let's check the edge (1->2)

Answer (score 1):

```
edgelist = {s -> 1, s -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 3 -> t, 4 -> 3, 4 -> t};

MemberQ[edgelist, 1 -> 2]
(* False *)

MemberQ[edgelist, 2 -> 1]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all the edges of this graph and to find if they are on this graph or not. for examle s->1 is from this graph but 1->s isn't.

Comment: @NasiJofce Look up `Table`, `Do`, `Outer`, and/or `Subsets`.  I think you need to spend some time learning the basics.